# How to access gridpanel from controller to save grid data to database

Tags: database, model-view-controller, controller, gridpanel

I have a `gridpanel` and I want to update the data in the grid to a database, but I am not able to access the grid in my controller so that I can proceed and update the database in the database.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far, so others can help you easier. Also post any errors you have.

Comment: In index.aspx <Proxy>
                    <ext:AjaxProxy Url="Shared/Test.ashx">
                    <Reader>
                    <ext:JsonReader Root="data" />
                    </Reader>
                    <Writer>
                    <ext:JsonWriter Root="data" Encode="true" WriteAllFields="false" />
                    </Writer>
                    <API Update="Shared/Test.ashx" />
                    </ext:AjaxProxy>
                    </Proxy>

Comment: Best to edit your post and put the code there.

Comment: In test.ashx    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var response = new StoreResponseData();
            var dataHandler = new StoreDataHandler(context);            List<Dictionary<string, object>> data = dataHandler.ObjectData<Dictionary<string, object>>();           foreach (Dictionary<string, object> list in data)
            { try
                {response.Data = JSON.Serialize(data);}
                catch (Exception e){
                    response.Success = false;
                    response.Message = e.Message;
                }  }  response.Return();}